# jQuery was not called while calling using jsonp

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, facebook

I'm using $.ajax call for the JSON data of a Facebook feed.

My link is `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/fbpage?fields=feed{full_picture}&access_token=xxxxxx77429|xxxxxxxx51a8b07978b66e11b&callback=jQueryfb`

My script is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/fbpage?fields=feed{full_picture}&access_token=xxxxxx77429|xxxxxxxx51a8b07978b66e11b&callback=jQueryfb',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Problem with call to get list \n', errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(oxo) {
        console.log('call success, data is\n', oxo);
        var tblRow = "<div>" + oxo + "</div>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo(".oxohere");
    }
});
```

It is working perfectly when I make a call from my local  files(without a local server), but when I host my pages it gives this error:

> Error: jQuery21303679574115667492_1454433330015 was not called

How should I solve this problem ?

Comment: Does Facebook support JSONP? Why not use the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Comment: @WizKid, it supports jsonp,and idk how to use fb js sdk, im learning things.